# Split single row into multiple rows in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linq

Have table like it below

```
Id crdid sedol comments
1   123   ABC   one
2   234   you   two
3   456   me    three
```

Now want to get

```
Id        1
Crdid     123
Sedol     ABC
Comments  one

Id        2
Crdid     234
Sedol     you
Comments  two
```

Please give me solutions
Thanks

Comment: What you expect as result? Probably classes? Some collection?

Comment: Want export to excel format which way is best to convert this

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do this:

Say, use a data list.

So, markup is this:

```
        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                ID: <asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                <br />
                crid: <asp:Label ID="cridLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("crid") %>' />
                <br />
                sedol: <asp:Label ID="sedolLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sedol") %>' />
                <br />
                comments: <asp:Label ID="commentsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("comments") %>' />
                <br />
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

code behind is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadData
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadData()

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblThings", conn)

            conn.Open()
            DataList1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
            DataList1.DataBind()

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.already loaded datatable dynamically on the page without using server controls like datalist,gridview ..I have  convert  those records into excel format..need to show those data(output what I expected) in excel

Comment: Well, I assume if exporting to Excel, then would not a grid like view be the better choice. You started out with a grid/table of data, then wanted a "non" grid format, and that's what the 2nd exmaple shows. I might thus be missing the goal here? If you send the data table to a grid-view, then you get a grid like result. If you send to a datalist, then you get a non columnar view. Your question suggest you looking for a "non" column (table) layout, but then you turn around and suggest you want to send to Excel, which would suggest a table like layout? So, to Excel I would think a table layout?

Comment: In other words, this suggests you do not want a table layout in Excel, but each record as shown. I would consider STILL using a grid/table in excel, and then from the menu in Excel use the view data as form option - better then trying to send data to excel as a non grid/table format.  Check out how to add/use the FORM option in Excel - it is built in and when you click on it, it displays a single row from the table in your 2nd format you want.